# Hide "phonebook contacts" from page but display results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a simple **Live Search script**, and it is very useful but i need one modification.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

This script use live search from "phonebook", and contacts from "phonebook" are displayed (visible) to everyone.

How to hide contacts from landing page, but to display them in search result field?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you'd like an autofill kind of effect?

Comment: Script is doing good job now, but i just need to hide all contacts from phonebook (now it is displayed on page), and if i type "Agnes" in search form, script will search phonebook and display contact "Agnes" if that contact exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDQGA5EHCMJP

```
#myUL li {
    display: none;
}

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (filter.length > 0 && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is still showing all phonebook contacts on page (from html code).

Comment: on the link I sent? You need to add the css class change too